# How to fill out the form with desired time rather than time selected from the chart?

Tags: cognito-forms

I am trying to have the time so that the people who fill out the form can just type the time they want, not select from the chart.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

We do not currently support the ability to disable the time picker widget on your form's public link. However, if your form is embedded, you can add an extra bit of code to your CSS to effectively hide the widget while still allowing people to type in the time:

```
.cognito-timepicker-widget {display: none !important;}
```